# make 'add_cascade' function with a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to know how I can display a "liste_box" in an "askquestion" window (I want to put it in an "askquestion" window so the page is handheld on the frame), also how to display a dropdown menu but not like in the menus we create with a label, etc. but rather on a button (so if you press a button a dropdown menu like "add_cascade" appears) actually the same as a menu but on a button and how I can search to find solutions to problems when I encounter them like this, because before I use chatgpt but I find with time that it can no longer answer my questions when I have some...

```py
def afficher_menu(self):
    liste_box = tkinter.Listbox(calculatrice)
    liste_box.insert(1, "CosH", command=fonction)
    liste_box.insert(2, "SinH", command=fonction)
    liste_box.insert(3, "TanH", command=fonction)
    liste_box.insert(4, "ArcCosH", command=fonction)
    liste_box.insert(5, "ArcSinH", command=fonction)

    messagebox.askquestion("Hyperbolique", liste_box)
```

have the possibility of having like the cascade with the menus but on a button

(I speak French and i have used a transator)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with tkinter, but FWIW, it might help to translate the code too so it's clearer for people who don't know French, e.g. `afficher_menu` -> `show_menu`, `calculatrice` -> `calculator`. See [mre] for related tips. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] if you want more tips.